# How change the storage location of recentf file?

Tags: recentf

I looked around, but I couldn't find any answer in the documentation of
        `recentf` and with <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `recent`.

My default directory is set with the following:

```
(setq user-emacs-directory "~/home/ReneFroger/"
       default-directory "~/home/ReneFroger/")
```

I noticed Emacs saves the recent files that I have visited in the file
`recentf`, which will be stored in the `home/ReneFroger/` path. 
I would like to change the location of `recentf` but I can't find any variable
that allows me to do this.

Comment: It's stored in `/Users/sth/.emacs.d/.cache/recentf` for me by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set it with

```
(setq recentf-save-file (expand-file-name "recentf" <other-directory>))
```

You can usually find settings like this by looking at the help for one of the functions, e.g. `recentf-mode`, then following the link to the source code, and then doing `occur` for `defcustom` to find one that looks like it might be a file storage location - e.g. in this case you'd get

```
 23 matches for "defcustom" in buffer: recentf.el
 65:(defcustom recentf-max-saved-items 20
 72:(defcustom recentf-save-file (locate-user-emacs-file "recentf" ".recentf")
 85:(defcustom recentf-save-file-modes 384 ;; 0600
 94:(defcustom recentf-exclude nil
111:(defcustom recentf-keep
etc.
```

Comment: Not only your answer, but the tip to follow the source code of `recentf` and then doing `occur` for `defcustom` was very valuable for me. Thanks for that!

Comment: From this link (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles) its advices to use `(setq recentf-save-file (recentf-expand-file-name <file_path>))`

Answer (score 2):

From the link (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles):

```
;; use a different set of recent files
(setq recentf-save-file (recentf-expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/.recentf"))
```